# Помогите добавить счетчик индексов в код

Tags: c#

Перед вами предоставлена программа, которая в массиве определяет индексы элементов, значение которых не меньше заданного минимума и не больше заданного максимума. Мне нужно, чтобы она считала выведенные индексы элементов.

```
string s;
int max, min;
Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива ");
s = Console.ReadLine();

string[] str = s.Split(' ');
int[] arr = new int[str.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine("Введите минимальный элемент ");
min = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите максимальный элемент ");
max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                   
Console.WriteLine("Индексы элементов");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if ((arr[i] > min) && (arr[i] < max))
    {
        Console.Write("{0} ", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Чтобы она считала" - как я понимаю, речь идёт всего навсего о выводе счетчика таких элементов.

Тогда это делается примерно так:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы массива ");
string s = Console.ReadLine();

string[] str = s.Split(' ');
int[] arr = new int[str.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine("Введите минимальный элемент ");
int min = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Введите максимальный элемент ");
int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           
Console.WriteLine("Индексы элементов");
int counter=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if ((arr[i] >= min) && (arr[i] =< max))
    {
        Console.Write($"{i} ");
        counter++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"{Environment.NewLine}Количество элементов: {counter}");
```

Обратите внимание, что я исправил условие в последнем цикле - если "начение которых не меньше заданного минимума и не больше заданного максимума", то надо делать сравнение >= и <=, а не > и <. Кроме того, я немного поправил вывод данных - начиная с C# 6.0 есть более удобный способ форматирования.